# how Create Database in SQLite Expert Professional 4 - 64bit?

Tags: android, sqlite

I do not know how should I create SQL Lite database.

when chosen New database option و I do not know what to do. [It Show Me This Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StGHE.png)

please guide me .

My SQLite Version : SQLite Expert Professional 4 - 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Try Sqlite Manager firefox plugin, is eassier there:
[Sqlite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Comment: i Need To Use SQLite Not SQLiteManger in Mozika

Answer (score 0):

File-->New Database-->Give a name for your database-->Click Open and the database is created!